# NoReverseMatch Error on Django Redirect

Tags: python, regex, django, redirect

I am getting the following exception in ***movie*** app of my django project:

> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /movie/
>   Exception Value: Reverse for 'movie.views.movie_detail' with arguments '(u'the_peanuts_movie',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Here are the url patterns of movie.urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<movie_name>[\w_]+)$', views.movie_detail, name='movie_detail'),
    url(r'^', views.movie_home, name='movie_home'),
]
```

Here are some parts of the movies.views.py:

```
def movie_detail(request, movie_name):
     # code
     ...

def movie_home(request):
    ...
    return redirect(movie_detail, movie_name)
    # movie_name is a string
```

So far, I cannot make this code work. But it works, if I change ***return statement*** and put this in ***movie_home function***:

```
    movie_name += '/'
    return redirect(movie_name)
```

Now after reading a few other questions of this type in stackoverflow, I know that the `return redirect(movie_name)` statement works since it redirects to an url:
***127.0.0.1:8000/movie/whatever_is_the_movie_name***

But I do not understand why redirecting to ***movie_detail*** view is not working.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, `movie_detail` should be a string (`'movie_detail'`) and under the `'movie'` namespace - also, try using reverse and passing in the name as an arg:

```
return redirect(reverse('movie:movie_detail', args=[movie_name]))
```

Also, it looks like you missed an ending slash in your `urls.py` before the `$`:

```
url(r'^(?P<movie_name>[\w_]+)/$', views.movie_detail, name='movie_detail'),
```

Comment: It does not work. Here is the exception:

**Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /movie/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'movie_detail' with arguments '(u'the_peanuts_movie',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []**

Comment: Updated my answer, add the second part to see if it works now

Comment: your solution worked, when I used **'movie:movie_detail'**...Is this because of a namespace issue?

Comment: Great! And yes, the namespace allows you to have similar names under different apps to avoid conflicts. Glad it worked!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was stuck with this problem for a long time and no other answer seems to mention this namespace issue!

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

movie.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^(?P<movie_name>[\w_]+)$', views.movie_detail, name='movie_detail'),
url(r'^', views.movie_home, name='movie_home'),
]
```

movie.views.py

```
def movie_detail(request, movie_name):
    # code
    ...

def movie_home(request):
    ...
    return redirect('movie:movie_detail', movie_name) #CHANGES : (appname:url_name as str)
    # movie_name is a string
```